# How to redirect to ASP.NET Error Pages when Session Sql database is down

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I have an ASP.NET Website which stores sessions in SQL Server. I have deliberately made my session databases offline to make sure that my error pages are being shown to users.

My Web.config :

```
 <system.webServer>
  <httpErrors errorMode="DetailedLocalOnly" existingResponse="Replace">
    <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="13" />
    <error statusCode="404" subStatusCode="13" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="LargeFileError.aspx" responseMode="Redirect" />
      <remove statusCode="500" />
      <error statusCode="500" path="Error.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL"/>
  </httpErrors>
 </system.webServer>

 <system.web>
  <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="/Error.aspx" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite">    
    <error statusCode="500" redirect="Error.aspx" />
  </customErrors>
</system.web>
```

My global.asax :

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           Exception exception = Server.GetLastError();
             Response.Clear();
            Server.ClearError(); 
           Response.Redirect("Error.aspx");     
        }
```

My Error.aspx Page is a simple page which just has a localized string. Hence, won't be able to make it html page.

I keep on getting this error :

> "The underlying provider failed on Open."

You might say that there are lot of solutions on stack overflow for this error, but my issue here is to show the Error Pages (An aspx  page when session db is down) rather than solve this error.

Even when I am navigating to error.aspx page directly, I am getting this error. 
I need a way to tell Asp.Net & IIS that I don't need session information for this particular page.

How do I solve this & ensure that my error page are getting shown.

Answer (score 0):

**In the existing connection string to remove the “user Instance=true” and it works.**

see details here:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dataaccesstechnologies/2012/08/09/error-the-underlying-provider-failed-on-open-in-entity-framework-application/#comment-17785

Comment: I don't need to solve the error message as I have made my database offline deliberately. I want users to be redirected to my error pages.

Answer (score 0):

So I did these things :

1) Change `Respose.redirect` to `Server.Transfer` in Global.asax

2) Added this setting on @Page Directive of Error.aspx

```
EnableSessionState="false"
```

3) I also had to manage My site.Master ( Error.aspx was a child page) had an Anti Xsrf validation which was throwing error.

```
  if (Context.User != null)
                {
                    ViewState[AntiXsrfUserNameKey] = Context.User.Identity.Name ?? String.Empty;
                }
                else {
                    ViewState[AntiXsrfUserNameKey] = String.Empty;
                }
```